# how do i detect the flashcard type(xd,sd) when i inserted a flashcard into my allinone usb cardreader in delphi?

Tags: delphi, cardreader

everyone.
I am new to here.
I have a question about how to detect flashcard type(XD,SD ) when I inserted a flashcard into my usb cardreader in a delphi app.
I have searched many topics and didn't find any good way.
any ideas?

---

thanks for your reply,TLama.
my friend's factory produce USB cardreader and he want to use a  soft to test all cardreader.
he hope that worker insert SD card instead of a  CF card when the test program says 'please insert SD card'  .
I got a pic of the IC OF cardreader.but i still have no idea how to do with it ?is there any way  to check  status of pin of the IC? 
[image]

[image]